# Issues with some CSS Selectors when using Python GTK3

Tags: python, css, css-selectors, gtk3

I am having some issues with getting some of my CSS Selectors to work with Python GTK3. Some of the expressions suggested at https://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/ (which is admittedly vintage reading) don't seem to work, and the description at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html#theme-inconsistent-checkbuttons (just below the example) also seems to suggest Selector syntax which doesn't always work.

I created a short Python test with a glade UI file. I was thinking I wouldn't include it unless it was requested, but since I've found examples that other people have posted to be very helpful, I think I'll go ahead and post it (pygtk3test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

CSS = b"""
#mainWindow {
    background-color: red;
}
GtkEntry {
    background-color: yellow;
}
"""

myBuilder = Gtk.Builder()
myBuilder.add_from_file("pygtk3test.glade")
window = myBuilder.get_object("mainWindow")
yesButton = myBuilder.get_object("yesButton")

# set up the CSS provider
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
style_provider.load_from_data(CSS)
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), style_provider,
                                     Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

And the glade file (pygtk3test.glade):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="name">mainWindow</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">250</property>
    <property name="default-height">100</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="halign">center</property>
        <property name="valign">center</property>
        <property name="spacing">50</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry">
            <property name="name">entry1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="text" translatable="yes">test1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry">
            <property name="name">entry2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="text" translatable="yes">test2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

So the first thing I found was that the "ID" on the General tab in Glade is not the E#id mentioned in the CSS Selectors description! You have to go to the Common tab and fill in the "Widget name". Once that is filled in the #id selector will work, like #mainWindow in this example, but only because that's what the "Widget name" is. So if I run the code, I get a red window background.

But "GtkEntry" (what is in the code above), or ".GtkEntry" (since the object has class="GtkEntry", I would expect that to work) don't give a yellow background. If I use a selector of "entry", that works, as that's the name of the CSS node. (If you run the code with "GTK_DEBUG=interactive" added into the environment, it opens a GTK3 debugger that can be helpful tracking down the nodes or hierarchy.) If I use the name of the widget, that also works, either "#entry1" or "entry#entry1". I don't think I've gotten anything to work with "GtkEntry" in the selector.

So now, after a lot of trial and error, I think I am able to create a CSS selector for all of the things I need, but not all of the selectors that seem like they should work do work.

Is there some other resource out there that better explains the creation of CSS selectors for use in GTK3?