# Multiple CSS Providers in Python GTK3

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I've read lots of posts about using CSS in GTK3 in Python, but I never really seemed to find anything about changing styles programmatically. Usually there is one big triple-quoted string that has all of the CSS definitions in it. But what if I want to change a single style programmatically in the code? If I modify the provider (load_from_data) with that single style, all of the other styles are lost (i.e. they revert to default).

I found one way that works, but I'd like to get some advice on whether that's the best way or not. I found that I can create and add **another** provider, and I can give it a higher priority, so any styles in it would override the styles in the big triple-quoted CSS string. The priorities are discussed here: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen, and the different priorities are explained here: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/constants.html#Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION.

Here's some sample code to demonstrate. Yes, I realize it's pretty strange code... create a window with a couple of entries with weird background colors. If you change the text in the **second** entry field, then the background of the two entries changes. But the point is that there is some point in the script where we want to change some styles on the fly (e.g. a font chooser has been executed to choose a new text font), and this seems to give us a mechanism for doing that. You will need to use the .glade file that is found in this post to run this code: [Issues with some CSS Selectors when using Python GTK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77517627/issues-with-some-css-selectors-when-using-python-gtk3).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

CSS = b"""
window {
    background-color: yellow;
}
entry {
    background-color: green;
}
"""

def text_changed(self, provider):
    text = self.get_text()
    print(text)
    newcss = "entry {background-color: red}"
    provider.load_from_data(bytes(newcss.encode()))


myBuilder = Gtk.Builder()
myBuilder.add_from_file("pygtk3test.glade")
window = myBuilder.get_object("mainWindow")
#objects = myBuilder.get_objects()
label2 = myBuilder.get_object("label2")
entry2 = myBuilder.get_object("entry2")

# set up the global CSS provider
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
style_provider.load_from_data(CSS)
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), style_provider,
                                     Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
user_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
user_provider.load_from_data(bytes("".encode()))
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), user_provider,
                                     Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

entry2.connect("changed", text_changed, user_provider)
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I'm open to any suggestions as to how this could be done better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen` as you are, except use the CSS to define a CSS class.  Then use the add and remove class functions to switch your widgets back and forth. (C code below, not C++).

```
gtk_style_context_add_class (
   gtk_widget_get_style_context (widget), class);

gtk_style_context_remove_class (
   gtk_widget_get_style_context (widget), class);
```

I have some static CSS defined in a file, I read that in, I append all the dynamic CSS configurations and use `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen` to set it.  From then on, only add and remove class are needed.

Comment: Thanks @Brad for your input. My problem: I don't have the details of the style configuration when the program first starts. I will obviously add a provider early in the program with my (big chunk of) static CSS. If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that if I have style definitions to modify later on, that I should add those definitions to the static CSS, then run provider.load_from_data again (I assume you wouldn't need add_provider_for_screen again?) to update the provider. That seems kind of "wasteful" since the static CSS could be quite large, but maybe that's not a problem?